# add SSJS action to a bootstrap pill

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have added a simple pill list as a navigator:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#">Profiles</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#">Applications</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#">Automation</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- COntainer -->
```

and it workd fine if all I want to do is add an href link, but I need to run some SSJS when the pill is clicked. Just starting the BootStrap hill so perhaps this is not doable. I have searched but have not been able to find how one would do that.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried replacing the HTML anchor tag with the _xp:link_ tag? Set the value (destination/href) to # and give it an onClick event with your SSJS _eventHandler_. Just keep it inside the _li_ and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<xp:link>` instead HTML `<a>`. It allows you to add an on click event with SSJS code:

```xml
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <xp:link
                escape="true"
                text="Profiles"
                id="link1">
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
                    submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("your SSJS code")}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:link>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <xp:link
            ...
```

`<xp:link>` gets rendered to an `<a>` tag finally like

```xml
<a id="view:_id1:link1" href="#" class="xspLink">Profiles</a>
```

You asked in your comment how to add `data-toggle="tab"` to rendered `<a ...>`. You can accomplish that with `<xp:this.attrs>` within `<xp:link>`:

```xml
        ...
            <xp:link
                escape="true"
                text="Profiles"
                id="link1">
                <xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr
                        name="data-toggle"
                        value="tab">
                    </xp:attr>
                </xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
        ...
```

The rendered link looks like this then

```xml
<a id="view:_id1:link1" href="#" class="xspLink" data-toggle="tab">Profiles</a>
```

Comment: Knut - As usual clear , straight forward and bang on! I knew there had to be a way but just could not find a reference to the method.

Comment: Your answer works great. I have a follow up. in the <a tag you can add data-toggle="tab" which toggles the active property, but since we have replaced the <a with the link there is no place to put the data-toggle statement. Is there a way to get it into the final rendered <a tag?

Comment: Bill, I extended my answer by added `data-toggle="tab"` in rendered `<a>` tag.

Comment: Knut - I created a panel and set the display:none and put all the links in the panel then added the <a id=view:_id1:myActions href="#" etc I get an error Invalid format for ID: view:_id1:myActions
view:_id1:myActions
Is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: <xp:panel id="panelMain">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
     <li role="presentation">
      <a id="view:_id1:myActions" href="#" class="xspLink"
       data-toggle="tab">Profiles</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </xp:panel>
 <xp:panel style="display:none">
  <xp:link id="myActions" text="My Actions">
   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dynamicContentMainView">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:"code"}]]></xp:this.action>
   </xp:eventHandler>
  </xp:link>
 </xp:panel>

Comment: Don't add `<a>` tag to XPage code, use `<xp:link ...` with `<xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr
                        name="data-toggle"
                        value="tab">
                    </xp:attr>
                </xp:this.attrs>` instead. My last line in answer shows only how it will be rendered and sent to browser. That isn't code you'd put into your XPage.

Comment: OK now I get it. Thanks